Preserve blank node identifiers in SPARQL results download
When I download the result of a SPARQL query in GraphDB 10.7.6 in N-Quad or N-Triples formats, the blank nodes are renamed with a generic _:genid prefix.
Is is possible to preserve blank node identifiers in SPARQL results downloads in N-Quad or N-Triples formats?
